# Batch File to enable a service in windows server 2003

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2003

A windows service in windows server 2003 keeps on disabling every day. I want to write a batch file which would check the status of the service and start it if its not running.
I did that with the following command

```
Net Start "Service_Name"
```

It works fine in starting a service whose Startup Type is either "Automatic" or "Manual" and does not start a service whose Startup Type is "Disabled"

I tried the following command

```
enable "SERVICE_NAME" SERVICE_AUTO_START
```

But this command is not supported by Windows Server 2003.
Can you guys help me as which command to be used to enable a service in Windows Server 2003?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't confirm this works for Server 2003 but it works for Win7, so worth a shot.

```
sc config "Service_Name" start= auto
net start "Service_Name"
```

Comment: Bali:
Yes this works. I found it in a you tube video. Let me add one thing that the space after the equal(=) sign is compulsory.
Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: No worries, yeah the space is needed for some strange reason, it's definitely a gotcha to watch out for!